# How to determine the range to calculate the last digit of the sum of Fibonacci numbers using Pisano Period?

Tags: python, range, fibonacci

I already solved this problem. If I understood correctly the logic is the following: since we need the last digit of a sum of Fibonacci numbers we can use:

```
n mod 10 == (n % Pisano 10) mod 10
```

My issue is with the range of the sum. I don't know how to find it. Since Pisano 10 = 60, the last digits repeat with a period of 60 so I don't need to calculate the Fibonacci values from 0 to N but I don't know how to determine this range.

I found solutions for this problem but I never understood how they found their range. For example:

[Original here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/last-digit-of-sum-of-numbers-in-the-given-range-in-the-fibonacci-series/#:%7E:text=%2B%20FN%20where%20FK,55%2C%2089%2C%20144%2C%20%E2%80%A6&text=%3D%3E%202%20%2B%203%20%2B%205,of%20the%20sum%20is%206.)

```
def sum_fib_last(n):
    if(n <= 1):
        return n

    previous = 0
    current  = 1

    rem = n % 60 #60 is Pisano period of 10

    for i in range(2, rem + 3): 
        
        previous, current = current, (previous + current) % 60
  
    return(current-1) % 10
```

I don't know why the range is from (2 to rem+3) and why we return the Fibo value minus 1. [Similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62102429/12178572)

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008721/12178572) uses a different range:

```
def last_digit(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range((n + 2) % 60):
        a, b = b, (a + b) % 10
    return 9 if a == 0 else a - 1
```

I need help to understand how these ranges where determined, I don't understand the logic behind them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should have been a little bit clearer.  The sum of the first n Fibonacci numbers is `Fib(n + 2) - 1`.  This is easy to prove by induction.